# How to detect environment method is running in JS util file (CRA)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

In my CRA app, util JS file, there is a method `pause` which I would like to change depending on the environment it's running.

```
class CompilationEngine {
  ...
  pause () {
    return new Promise(resolve => emitter.once('next', resolve))
  }
  ...
}
```

I want `pause` function to return `Promise.resolve()` in test environment(when I run `npm run start`) since some tests are failing due to `next` event not emitted in console test. So how can I
detect the environment and change the code inside `pause` function.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough what environment you want to detect. It seems that it's test environment but it's barely mentioned. It's likely XY problem as for testing you can and commonly will mock things that need to behave differently in tests.

Comment: Use mocks instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

right?

Answer (score 0):

### Quickly answer

In CRA you can use environment variables declaring them before the `npm run start`

You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Example:

```
export REACT_APP_DISABLE_NEXT = true
```

CRA framework will expose this operative system level variable to a simple javascript variable ready to use in any part of your react code:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE
```

source:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

### Explanation

Environment variables like `export FOO=BAR` are variables at operative system level. These variables are easy accessed with:

```
process.env.FOO
```

React is not a nodejs javascript. React will be converted to vanilla javascript to be able to run in a browser. In this javascript process.env does not exist.

But CRA Framework (which is nodejs), have access to the operative system variables, so it create us an emulation of **process.env** containing just variables which start with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variable without `REACT_APP_`, will be ignored

### Advice

- Expose `export REACT_APP_DISABLE_NEXT = true` just in dev or test stage, not in prod