# how do i use environment variables in my react project?

Tags: reactjs, api-key, dotenv

I am trying to save my API key as an environment variable, but I don't know how to reach it... I npm installed dotenv, created the file in the root directory, and put the key there. I try to access it in a js file by using process.env.API_KEY but it says that the variable is undefined.

I tried putting `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of the file I need the key in, but it gives me an error...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in ...
```

I think I am either putting it in the wrong file, or I am missing something entirely

Answer (score 0):

As a summary:

To read the **API_KEY** variable in your react layer, you will need to export the variale
**REACT_APP_API_KEY** before the build and the on any react part, you could get the value with

```
process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

Check the links to understand why the prefix **REACT_APP_** is required.

Also if your token is a long live or non non-expirable token, you should not expose it to the frontend (react). Only expirable tokens ([authorization code oauth2 grant](https://docs.vmware.com/en/Single-Sign-On-for-VMware-Tanzu-Application-Service/1.14/sso/GUID-grant-types.html)) should be exposed to the frontend layer.

Check the references to understand how to handle the frontend variables

### References

- [How to detect environment method is running in JS util file (CRA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955257/how-to-detect-environment-method-is-running-in-js-util-file-cra/64955459#64955459)
- [Is it possible to use a React server enviroment variables into frontend at client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66883900/is-it-possible-to-use-a-react-server-enviroment-variables-into-frontend-at-clien/66915031#66915031)
- [How to fetch with Axios using Env secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839655/how-to-fetch-with-axios-using-env-secret-key/75839817#75839817)
- [Get React to talk to backend API server on a different EC2 instance in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358223/get-react-to-talk-to-backend-api-server-on-a-different-ec2-instance-in-productio/63360519#63360519)
- [How to use variable substitution in Frontend js applications like backend applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220775/how-to-use-variable-substitution-in-frontend-js-applications-like-backend-applic/54271114#54271114)